# How to find where prototype is being used?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

We have 600 jsp files and I need to find out where we are using prototype.

Is searching for "$(" the best way to do this?

Will it catch all instances of searching for where prototype is being used? (If not, please provide what you would search for)

Comment: Are you attempting to determine if a page in particular uses Prototype or are you trying to replace Prototype's usage completely and thus, need to know everywhere a Prototype function is used?

Comment: I would like to know if any page is using Prototype in any way (I want to know if we even need the Prototype library-- i.e. is it actually being used by any of our pages)

Comment: You could always comment it out and see what breaks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$ is a good start, but depending on the programmer's style, they may be doing things like:

```
Element.hide('someDiv')
```

...which is another format to do the same thing. Finding $ will only help you find DOM manipulation functions, but there are plenty of other things Prototype.js can do, such as Ajax:

```
new Ajax.Request(....
```

Now if I do something like this, there are parts of it that are based on Prototype but simply looking for $ is not the answer:

```
var myDiv = $('someDiv') <-- obvious
myDiv.down('active').show()  <-- not obvious
```

or how about:

```
this.select('.someClass')
```

...all of these use Prototype. So in a nutshell, you need to know what the code is doing, as well as what parts of the code use Prototype.